# Why is this Java method reported as a bridge method?

Tags: java, jls

Consider the following Java program:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
public class BridgeTest {

    public static class ClassA {
        public void foo() {
        }
    }

    protected static class ClassB extends ClassA {
        @Override
        public void foo() {
        }
    }

    public static class ClassC extends ClassB {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Method method = ClassC.class.getMethod("foo");
        System.out.println(method + " -> isBridge() = " + method.isBridge());
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
public void BridgeTest$ClassC.foo() -> isBridge() = true
```

Looking more closely, `javap` reports:

```
public BridgeTest$ClassC();
...
  public void foo();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_BRIDGE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #2                  // Method BridgeTest$ClassB.foo:()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 15: 0
```

So clearly the compiler has synthesized the method `ClassC.foo()`, which makes sense because otherwise the method you'd get from instrospection is `ClassB.foo()` which won't be as usable because it's a member of a non-public class.

That explains the `ACC_SYNTHETIC` flag...

But why the `ACC_BRIDGE` flag?

The Javadoc for `Method.isBridge()` says it returns true *if this method is a bridge method as defined by the Java Language Specification.*

But I can't find any actual definition in the JLS.

This is not a "bridge method" under the normal definition of that term as I've understood it, which is one created to handle narrowing types due to generics and type erasure.

Perhaps there's really just some ambiguity here, in which case `Method.isBridge()` needs a more precise definition... ?

```
$ javac -version
javac 11.0.12
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I think this is the "bridge method" in the general sense, simply forwarding to other methods. A lot of articles say that "bridge method" is for type erasure, but I think that's just one of his functions.

Comment: I think you're right. But there is still a problem, which is that "bridge method" does not actually appear to be precisely defined anywhere.